# How to transfer together with clicking the button, the variable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I do not know the name of the button that I transmit.
In order to further work with the data, I need to transfer at least a id.
But when I try to send something else along with the event, an error appears.
I have Sqlite Database

```
for (int i = 0; i < database.Rows.Count; i1++)
{
    Button buttonNew  = new Button();
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["id"]); //i get id elem of my database 
    buttonNew.Click += ButtonNewClick(id);
}
void ButtonNewClick(int id)
{
    Form2 fNext = new Form2();
    fNext.Show();
    //Other operations...
}
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong ...
Are can you help me?

Comment: What does 'transmit a button'  mean?

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp - Need to get the button id(

Comment: Hmm, all that buttons go out of scope when the next iteration of the loop begins and I don't see code adding the button to some form or other control. So I doubt anyone is ever clicking on any of these... Anyway, you can have a look at [`Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.8) as a quick fix to store the ID in. Or make your own custom button class with a property for the ID.

Comment: @sticky bit - Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the ID in the **TAG** property of your dynamic button, then you can retrieve it later by casting the "sender" to button in the click event:

```
    private void Foo()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.Rows.Count; i1++)
        {
            Button buttonNew = new Button();
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["id"]); //i get id elem of my database 
            buttonNew.Tag = id; // store the ID for later retrieval
            buttonNew.Click += ButtonNew_Click;
            // ... add "buttonNew" to something ...
        }

    }

    private void ButtonNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        int id = (int)btn.Tag;
        // ... do something with "id" ...
    }
```

Note that the **SIGNATURE** of the click handler has changed.

Comment: Thanks. I really happy)